# Can two different `publisher sockets` publish messages on same address and port using zmq?

Tags: node.js, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have two **different node.js processes** (different publisher socket instances) need to publish messages using **different topics** but on **same address and port using zmq**. 
 Is it right way to do that or whether it is always good to use different address and port for different publisher socket instances?
Please note that I use different topics for different publishers.

Comment: I think if you try to bind to the same address and port twice, you will get an address in use exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Calling `Socket.Bind()` from two different process on the same address and port is going to result in a ZeroMQ "Address in Use" exception.

[Luckily](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out)!

> A subscriber can connect to more than one publisher, using one connect
>   call each time. Data will then arrive and be interleaved
>   ("fair-queued") so that no single publisher drowns out the others.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes! Use zmq.FORWARDER device:

http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/forwarder.html